# RadioButton. Calculate the formula of the corresponding button, ignoring the X range

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button

When you enter an argument x and click the Button, it checks which of the three ranges
hits x, the calculations are performed and the result is displayed in the TextView.
In this case, the corresponding radio button becomes marked
If you click another radio button, the calculations are recalculated for the formula corresponding to this button, a new result is displayed in the TextView, the range in which x is located is ignored
The problem is that when you click on another radio button, it still calculates according to the formula in which the X value falls.
I would like to ask for help. I tried changing the conditions and it didn't work

Program code

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.RadioButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlin.math.pow
import kotlin.math.sin
import kotlin.math.sqrt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var editTextX: EditText
    private lateinit var buttonCalculate: Button
    private lateinit var textViewResult: TextView
    private lateinit var radioButtonFormula1: RadioButton
    private lateinit var radioButtonFormula2: RadioButton
    private lateinit var radioButtonFormula3: RadioButton
    private lateinit var checkBoxDouble: CheckBox

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        editTextX = findViewById(R.id.editTextX)
        buttonCalculate = findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate)
        textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textViewResult)
        radioButtonFormula1 = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFormula1)
        radioButtonFormula2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFormula2)
        radioButtonFormula3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFormula3)
        checkBoxDouble = findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDouble)

        buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener {
            calculateResult()
        }

        // Initial installation of radio buttons
        radioButtonFormula1.isChecked = true
    }

    private fun calculateResult() {
        val x = editTextX.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()

        if (x != null) {
            val result = when {
                x <= 2 -> {
                    radioButtonFormula1.isChecked = true
                    sin(x + 1)
                }
                x > 2 && x < 3 -> {
                    radioButtonFormula2.isChecked = true
                    sqrt(x.pow(3) - 1)
                }
                else -> {
                    radioButtonFormula3.isChecked = true
                    x + 1.5
                }
            }

            if (checkBoxDouble.isChecked) {
                textViewResult.text = (result * 2).toString()
            } else {
                textViewResult.text = result.toString()
            }
        } else {
            textViewResult.text = "Please enter a valid value x"
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="100dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCalculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkBoxDouble"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Calculate" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDouble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:text="Double your result" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextX"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:hint="Enter value x"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/buttonCalculate"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonFormula1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Formula 1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonFormula2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Formula 2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonFormula3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Formula 3" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```